# Eclipse "An error has occurred. See the log file"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> Eclipse "An error has occurred. See the log file" C:\Program Files\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\eclipse\configuration\1663787406897.log.

with the actual log being

> 

```
!SESSION 2022-09-21 16:03:50.380 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
java.version=19
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pt_BR
Framework arguments:  -XX:-UseCompressedOops -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -XX:-UseCompressedOops -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-09-21 16:03:50.631
!MESSAGE error loading hook: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseHookConfigurator
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @62043840
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:387)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:363)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:311)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:201)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findMethod(BaseStorage.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findMethod(BaseStorage.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findAddURLMethod(BaseStorage.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.<init>(BaseStorage.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseHookConfigurator.addHooks(BaseHookConfigurator.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookRegistry.loadConfigurators(HookRegistry.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookRegistry.initialize(HookRegistry.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.<init>(BaseAdaptor.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.createAdaptor(EclipseStarter.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-09-21 16:03:50.690
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initialize(org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor)" because "this.storage" is null
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

I couldn't find any board that dealt with this

Comment: You are trying to run an ages old version of eclipse (according to the information in the path from 19 February 2013, which is over nine years ago) with a current JVM (java.version=19). That simply doesn't work. If you must use that old version of eclipse then you must run it with Java 1.7 or Java 1.8.

Comment: Also note that since about 2017 the preferred way to develop for Android is using the [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/). There might be features available in Android that you cannot use with Eclipse+ADT from 2013.

Comment: I figured it out a few minutes ago, but thank you for the answer. And yes, I have to use this version of Eclipse since this is the one our teacher assigned to us, but we will switch to Android Studio in the next Bimester!

Answer (score -4):

Your eclipse doesn't work because you are trying to open it a java version not compatible with it, so you can try this (it works for me): go to file explorer and search your eclipse folder and open, search the file eclipse.in and put this after `openFile`:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\YouJDKVersion\bin\javaw.exe
```

Source: [JVM eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)